# Positioning field in Acumatica FormView

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to place the 'Location' field below Business Account in the Page 'Cases'. Here is what I have done.
[image]

And when I preview, it looks as expected.
[image]
But when I load the page, it gets placed in a wrong place like this.
[image]

What should I do?

Comment: We are assuming you published your change?

Comment: I did publish the project.

Comment: I typically just set the aspx entry directly. This can be done from within the layout editor under Actions > Edit ASPX. Then find your field entry and make sure its after your field. When you move it and want to save its location, click "Generate Customization Script" and your project xml should update with the change.

Comment: Your work looks good and I've tested it. If you did a few change before that it can be an old version of Runtime Code DLL which is stuck. From an administrator command prompt run 'iisreset' and try again or restart website from IIS manager (inetmgr.exe).

Comment: Also, verify that a Layout Rule for Service Management section is not interfering.

Comment: It's actually already under 'Business Account' field even in ASPX. And even to make sure that the change is there, I checked the xml too. Here is the screenshot from aspx and xml files.
https://snag.gy/iGRDBg.jpg
https://snag.gy/Wv0KNC.jpg

Comment: I did reset the website but no luck. And I am unable to find Service Management section too in Layout Editor.

Comment: Check if the ASPX page is in CstPublished folder in your Acumatica instance folder. Also try to unpublish every customization except yours. It could be a conflict with Service Management.

Comment: Yeah. "Cases' page was also customized in another project called 'Service Management'. So, I opened the file 'CR306000.aspx' from CstPublished directory and made changes there, and it worked. Though it worked, is it the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yeah it's a good way to avoid conflicts since both Screen customization will be validated in a single package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check conflicts between customization projects, more than one project could be customizing the same screen.

1. Unpublish every customization project except yours.
2. If this resolves the issue, publish other customizations one by one until you find the conflicting one.
3. Merge both changes in the same customization project if possible. Otherwise you can try to adjust the Level field in the customizations screen to change the order in which customizations are applied, this can sometimes be enough.